# Change colors in colormap based on range of values

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colorbar

Is it possible to set the lower and/or upper parts of a colorbar based on ranges of values? For example, given the ROYGBIV colormap below and optionally an `offset` and a `range` value, I'd like to change the colors below `offset` and/or above `range`. In other words, suppose `offset = 20` and `range = 72`, I'd like to color all the values less than or equal to 20 in black and all values greater than or equal to 72 in white. I'm aware of the methods `set_under` and `set_over`, but they require changing the parameters `vmin` and `vmax` (as far as I know), which is not what I want. I want to keep the original minimum and maximum values (e.g., `vmin = 0` and `vmax = 100`), and only (optionally) change the colors of the extremities.

```py
ROYGBIV = {
    "blue": ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
             (0.167, 1.0, 1.0),
             (0.333, 1.0, 1.0),
             (0.5, 0.0, 0.0),
             (0.667, 0.0, 0.0),
             (0.833, 0.0, 0.0),
             (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
    "green": ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
              (0.167, 0.0, 0.0),
              (0.333, 0.0, 0.0),
              (0.5, 1.0, 1.0),
              (0.667, 1.0, 1.0),
              (0.833, 0.498, 0.498),
              (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
    "red": ((0.0, 0.5608, 0.5608),
            (0.167, 0.4353, 0.4353),
            (0.333, 0.0, 0.0),
            (0.5, 0.0, 0.0),
            (0.667, 1.0, 1.0),
            (0.833, 1.0, 1.0),
            (1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
}

rainbow_mod = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap("rainbow_mod", ROYGBIV, 256)
```

[image: Original colorbar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to do it using `ListedColormap` as explained [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html). The basic idea is to obtain the RGBA lists/tuples of the colors in the `LinearSegmentedColormap` object (`numpy` array) and replace the first or last few lists with replicates of the desired color.

It looks something like this:

```py
under_color = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]  # black (alpha = 1.0)
over_color = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]  # white (alpha = 1.0)

all_colors = rainbow_mod(np.linspace(0, 1, 256))

vmin = 0.0
vmax = 100.0

all_colors[:int(np.round((20.0 - vmin) / (vmax - vmin) * 256)), :] = under_color
all_colors[int(np.round((72.0 - vmin) / (vmax - vmin) * 256)):, :] = over_color

rainbow_mod_list = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(all_colors.tolist())
```

[image: Modified colorbar]